# How to make MiKTeX show installer

Tags: packages, miktex

So I accidentally hit "Do not show again" or something to that effect for the MiKTeX automatic package installer (the window that appears if you compile a file that references a package that isn't installed). I want it back, but couldn't find the option in MiKTeX anywhere.

Is this a Windows option? Or am I missing the setting in MiKTeX?

Comment: it is in the miktex console in the settings tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open the MiKTeX settings app and change it to (see marked place with red arrow):

[image]